# What should a sitemap look like when there are two domains for a website?

Tags: seo, domains, url, sitemap, multiple-domains

I have a website which has two domains. The nav looks like this:

- example.com
- example.com/page1/

  - example.com/page1/subpage1/
  - example.com/page1/subpage2/
- example.com/page2/
- example.net (which has exactly the same look as example.com, but it exists only for the keyword in the domain name)

  - example.net/page1/
  - example.net/page2/
- example.com/page3/

In this case what should the sitemap look like?

Is it a good practise to do have a second domain like this? Are there SEO benefits of creating multiple domains per website to have keywords in URL?

Comment: Having more than one domain for a site does absolutely nothing. Nothing at all. Stop the keyword chase. Search engines do not match keywords directly and have not for 2 decades now. All the SEO keyword BS is just that, BS. Search is about matching search intent with content using semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the keyword in the domain or URL plays very little role in ranking, so in my view probably it's not a good idea to have similar site structure on a secondary domain just because you would like to rank for a particular keyword.

Important: It may be OK to have the secondary site with similar structure but content must be unique on secondary domain.

As soon as you talk about different domain it will have its own sitemap.

In my view, unless the keywords you are targeting are in a different niche you shouldn't plan to have a separate site to target keywords you would like to rank for.

I would say think in detail about the product and service and think from customer point of view to solve the problem in a proper way.